# How to avoid undefined error in Typescript when extending?

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

My Typescript file:

```
interface BaseDefaultData{
  names: string[];
}

interface ExtendedDefaultData extends BaseDefaultData{
  defaultItems: {results: string[]; function: (props: string) => void;};
}

interface BaseProps {
  items: number;
  defaultData: BaseDefaultData;
}

interface ExtendedProps extends Omit<BaseProps, 'defaultData'>{
  defaultData: ExtendedDefaultData;
}

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = T extends any
  ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>>
  : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>;

type Props = StrictUnion<BaseProps | ExtendedProps>;
```

I have `strictNullChecks` set to `true`. I'm having some issues in areas like:

```
defaultData.defaultItems?.results ?? [];

if(defaultData.defaultItems){
  defaultData.defaultItems.function(doSomething);
};
```

`Typescript` keeps complaining about `Property 'defaultItems' does not exist on type 'BaseProps' every single place where I have` defaultData.defaultItems`.` Yes, on one side it is the case, but for that I have checks using ternary operator in one place and `if` prop exist in another, so ideally I would expect not to have errors everywhere, because I check for prop existence. I can avoid error by having `defaultData['defaultItems']` written instead, but it feels like I'm tricking `Typescript`. I expected checks that I have sufficient and don't understand why they don't work? What would be a proper way of handling it?

Component can be called by either:

```
<Component items={3} defaultData={{names: ['white', 'blue', 'red']}}/>
```

Or using

```
import {setItems} from '../../../redux/actions/itemActions';

<Component items={3} defaultData={{names: ['white', 'blue', 'red'], defaultItems: {results: ['1324', '6754232', '676729'], function: setItems}}}/>
```

Comment: Could you make this a [mre] by defining the `defaultData` variable? Ideally we could copy and paste your code into our IDEs and immediately see what you're seeing instead of having to try to reconstruct it.

Comment: jcalz, added case for `defaultData`

Comment: Sorry, this makes it worse, since now I don't have `Component` and it apparently relies on React, a third-party library not tagged in the question. I suggest you paste your code into a standalone IDE like The TypeScript Playground, and make sure that the problem you are asking about is the only one present.  Then put the plaintext here.  If that happens I'll check back, otherwise good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Jcalz was asking you for a repro like [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/NDJllW) where accessing defaultItems is an error even though the code apparently checks for it...

```
interface BaseDefaultData{
  names: string[];
}

interface ExtendedDefaultData extends BaseDefaultData{
  defaultItems: {results: string[]; function: (props: string) => void;};
}

interface BaseProps {
  items: number;
  defaultData: BaseDefaultData;
}

interface ExtendedProps extends Omit<BaseProps, 'defaultData'>{
  defaultData: ExtendedDefaultData;
}

function Component({defaultData}: BaseProps | ExtendedProps){
  if(defaultData.defaultItems){
    defaultData.defaultItems?.results ?? [];
    defaultData.defaultItems.function("doSomething");
  }
}
```

However the check you are attempting is itself not valid code, since the defaultItems member is not present for all members of the union, so you can't access it and check its truthiness.

However, you can ask if a key exists on an object (whether it exists or not). So if you use the guard `if("defaultItems" in defaultData){` instead, this can differentiate between union types and settle on the Extended ones...

```
interface BaseDefaultData{
  names: string[];
}

interface ExtendedDefaultData extends BaseDefaultData{
  defaultItems: {results: string[]; function: (props: string) => void;};
}

interface BaseProps {
  items: number;
  defaultData: BaseDefaultData;
}

interface ExtendedProps extends Omit<BaseProps, 'defaultData'>{
  defaultData: ExtendedDefaultData;
}

function Component({defaultData}: BaseProps | ExtendedProps){
  if("defaultItems" in defaultData){
    defaultData.defaultItems?.results ?? [];
    defaultData.defaultItems.function("doSomething");
  }
}
```

See [this typescript playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5jlMm) for the solution.